# pandas convert yes no to o/1

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a yes,no column (voice mail plan) in my dataframe (telecom) and I am going to convert it to 0,1. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiPbQ.png)

using following syntax I converted:

```
telecom['voice mail plan'] = telecom['voice mail plan'].map({'yes': 1, 'no': 0})
```

but as you see in the following image the values of my column (voice mail plan) turn to `NaN`.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nF69z.png)

Could you please let me know what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think there should be some traling spaces, then use [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

Test it:

```
print (telecom['voice mail plan'].unique().tolist())
```

---

```
telecom['voice mail plan'] = telecom['voice mail plan'].str.strip().map({'yes': 1, 'no': 0})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as I said I have no problem for converting the values . After converting the values turn to NaN values!!!

Comment: @asadyarahmadi - What return `print (telecom['voice mail plan'].unique().tolist())` ?

Answer (score 1):

From your question I get that you want to change the "Yes" in the Series to 1 and the "No" to 0.

The below code should solve your problem.

```py
telecom['voice mail plan'] = telecom['voice mail plan'].replace("yes", 1)
telecom['voice mail plan'] = telecom['voice mail plan'].replace("no", 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice approach here might be pd.Categorical:

```
telecom['voice mail plan'] = pd.Categorical(telecom['voice mail plan']).codes
```

Answer (score 0):

I think lambda function is a good option for this problem

```
telecom['voice mail plan']=telecom.apply(lambda x : 1 if x['voice mail plan']=='yes' else 0, axis=1)
```

Comment: Would you mind to provide any explanation to your answer please?

Comment: Basically, i define lambda function with if statement then apply all of column 'voice mail plan' and converted into same column.